# python POST request and null value

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm using the following code , to do POST request on application level

```
url = 'http://www.webdev.com/web/POST'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload = {'name': 'name', 'status': 'success', 'newname': 'name'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
r.text
r.status_code
r.connection.close()
```

from Python logs

```
send: 'POST /web/POST HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.webdev.com\r\nContent-Length: 189\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.8.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n\r\n'
send: '{"name": "test1", "status": "sucsses", "newname": "name23"}'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
```

but on the application level, it gives null value for the 3 vars.

The application is expecting the following format:

```
http://www.webdev.com/web/POST?name=test1&status=sucsses&newname=name23
```

I used curl command to do the post and application got the right value

Comment: It's more common for the POST body to contain the payload. Are you sure the desired behaviour is to use query string parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **aren't passing** your params as part of url and sending them in `POST` body, but server is waiting for GET params.

To pass your `payload` as GET parameters use [params](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) keyword argument:

```
r = requests.post(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

According to your url format you should ignore passing `data`, simply pass `params`.

**Good luck!**

Comment: and i should ignore  data=json.dumps(payload) ?